# At WPF using Live Charts, Can I add emphasis line on multiple specific label?

Tags: wpf, graph, livecharts

I'm using wpf with live charts library. 
While I draw line chart, I want to add emphasis line on specific label.
It can be a important date with an event.

At first, I added another lineseries about the event. to use geometry
as a marker. But the geometry is somewhat small. Therefore some people couldn't find the event data.

So I want to add lines at tham. But I don't know how to.
Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: First of all, you can modify the size of the point (no need for additional line), but if you would like another line, you can just add another line, with a big point label. Let me know if you know. Please also add code what you already have.

Comment: You _can_ abuse AxisSections to achieve a result like this: https://imgur.com/SQd8DRO. Here is the documentation: https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Sections. For your purpose, the XAML would be something like `<lvc:AxisSection Value="3" SectionWidth="0" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2"/>` on the x-axis, with 0 SectionWidth and a Stroke (the SectionWidth property is in axis steps, not pixels). The trouble with using PointGeometry is that Live Charts will automatically adjust the canvas to fit them, so you can’t really make lines full height afaik.